# How to get all the filenames of the files inside a folder in Ruby

Tags: ruby, file, hash, io, directory

I have a method that accepts path to folder and I want to get all the files names that have the extension '.yml' and add them into hash of pairs that look like this:

if the filename is **saved_file_1.yml** -> `{saved_file_1 => "saved_file_1.yml"}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Dir::glob`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Dir.html#method-c-glob) method as below

```
Dir.glob("#{path}/*.yml").each_with_object({}) do |filename,hsh|
   hsh[File.basename(filename,'.yml')] = filename
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hash = {}
Dir["#{path}/*.yml"].each { |f| hash[File.basename(f,'.yml')] = f }
```

Comment: Look the example - `File.basename("foo.yml",'.yml') # => "foo" ;
File.basename("foo.yml")  # => "foo.yml"`.. so your `File.basename(f)` wouldn't meet the OP's need.

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of matching files use [`Dir.glob`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Dir.html#method-c-glob) to get the list of files in the directory and [`File.extname`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-extname) to get the name of the extensions

```
Dir.glob(path_to_folder).select { |file| File.extname(file) == ".yml" }
```

To convert them into a hash like you have in your question, use [`File.basename`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-basename) to get the names of the file without the extension, and [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) to create a hash object

```
Dir.glob(path_to_folder).each_with_object({}) { |file, hash| hash[File.basename(file, ".yml")] = file }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
Hash[(d = Dir["#{path}/*.yml"]).map { |f| File.basename(f,".yml") }.zip(d)]
```